# Access (.mdb) file corrupted during servlet write to the client

Tags: java, servlets, outputstream, corrupt, jackcess

This was originally a part 2 of a different thread, but another use suggested that I separate the part 2 into it's own topic, so here we go.  Original thread is here ([Original Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137399/create-an-access-2013-database-file-and-send-to-user-via-servlet))

I am using Jackcess to create a V2010 mdb file that I need to transfer to a client that will use Access 2013 to open it.  Jackcess itself works - V2010 creates a file that Access 2013 can open when the file is FTP'd to the client by a third party software, such as FAR.  However, when I try to upload this file to the client through the servlet (as is the goal of this project), Access on the client says "Unrecognized database format "...file name...".  This is the code used for upload.  Code itself works, file is transferred, has a non-zero size if it's saved - but Access cannot open it.

Note, for content type I also tried vnd.msassess and octed-stream, with same unsuccessful results.  Also, I tried closing the db and creating the FileInputStream from the file name, and, as in the example, tried to create FileInputStream by calling mydb.getFile().  No difference.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-access");
String fileName = "SomeFileName.mdb"; 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
Database mydb = generateMDBFile();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mydb.getFile());
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
try {
     int byteRead = 0;
     while ((byteRead = fis.read()) != -1) {
           os.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
     }
     os.flush();
 } catch (Exception excp) {
     excp.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     os.close();
     fis.close();
 }
```

Why does this code corrupt the mdb file?  This happens every time, regardless of the size (I tried a tiny 2 column/1 row file, and a huge file with 40 columns and 80000 rows)

Thank you!

Comment: Try looking at the original file and the corrupted one with a hex editor. This could help you figuring out, if the file is just truncated (not fully transmitted), if the content is totally wrong (maybe bad or missing encoding/decoding at one of the end points), or if just some bytes (maybe upper-ascii-byte values, just a guess) got corrupted during transmission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to fill the buffer.
Use

```
// ...
while ((byteRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
       os.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
 }
// ...
```

Comment: I cannot believe I have been so blind.  That is, indeed, the answer.  On the bright side, while trying to get the transfer to work, I have added a zip option which works also.  Thanks again!